# Understand ookla speedtest json values

Tags: speed-test

I'm having some difficulties matching the json results with the values shown on the website:

I run the test with `speedtest -f json-pretty -u bps`

```json
{
    "type": "result",
    "timestamp": "2022-03-16T01:40:00Z",
    "ping": {
        "jitter": 68.655000000000001,
        "latency": 11.285
    },
    "download": {
        "bandwidth": 804925,
        "bytes": 5394240,
        "elapsed": 6706
    },
    "upload": {
        "bandwidth": 97467,
        "bytes": 1321920,
        "elapsed": 15005
    },
    "result": {
        "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "url": "https://www.speedtest.net/result/c/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "persisted": true
    }
}
```

But when I go to the url, I see this:
[image]

How do those 3 download values become 6.44Mbps ?

Answer (score 4):

Those 3 values mean:

**Bandwidth** - Actual internet download speed in **Bps** (Bytes per second), from `man speedtest`:

> The human-readable format  defaults  to  Mbps
> and  any machine-readable formats (csv, tsv, json, jsonl, json-pretty) use bytes as the unit of measure with max precision.

To get value in Mbps, as in following image you have to **divide it by 125000**:

> The bytes per second measurements can be transformed into the human-readable output format default unit of megabits (Mbps) by dividing the bytes per second value by 125,000.

**Bytes** - Volume of data used during the test (also in bytes)

**Elapsed** - Duration of testing download speed, in ms - how much time the testing took.